# SSH login not accepted, and no delay between ssh login attempts

Tags: ssh, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, openssh

When ssh'ing to my server (RaspPi running Arch), it doesn't accept my password (which I'm 98% sure is correct), and the usual delay before `Permission denied, please try again.` is not there. Elsewise, the server is running fine.

I tried using the default `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to no avail. Login with root is the same, no delay before asking the password again.

I don't have any monitor to connect to the Pi, so can't check journalctl and similar, but I have physical access to the sd card.

As mentioned, I've set ssh_config and sshd_config to default, and am utterly confused as to why openssh is behaving like this.

Here's `ssh -v` to root with ip retracted (don't see anything unusual myself):

```
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to ****.com [**.***.***.**] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to *********.com:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:TPjpBFxCBTcJR+zUv0KRTd3ImVCWzAk8D2U++W422oA
debug1: Host '******.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/****/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/****/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/****/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@*******.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@******.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
root@******com's password:
```

Comment: Are you logging in as root? If so, check the `PermitRootLogin` entry in `sshd_config`; this is the behavior you get if that's set to `prohibit-password`.

Comment: Encountered the problem when logging in as my normal user, so tried to set `PermitRootLogin yes` and logging in as root. It didn't help, and still no delay before asking for password again, which I find really weird.

Comment: Server error log usually provides more information about the failed logins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ams, I got access to the logs, where it seemeed to be a problem with PAM. I disabled pam-authentication in `sshd_config`, and was able to log in as root. There I could do a system update (in which pam had a new version), and logging in as my normal user is now possible.

However, for some reason the pause between login attempts over ssh is still not there (which obviously is a seriuos security problem), but I'll post a separate question about this if need be.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use `journalctl` on any computer to read the logs from the SD card. There are `--root` and `--directory` options for this purpose.

If you don't use Arch on your PC then the LiveCD/USB should do the job just fine.

@Brean's guess that `PermitRootLogin` is not set would be my guess, but you don't give enough information for me to say so specifically.

If root login is permitted, and the password still isn't accepted then you can edit the password on the SD card manually, but it might be easier to generate an ssh key and paste it into `/home/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.